# Convert Ellipsis path to Absolute path

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Just a quick question,
I have a path,

```
"../../../../Items/Image/rise.png"
```

I want to retrieve it's full path as

**C:\MyWeb\Items\Image\rise.png**

How do I do it in C#,

`Server.MapPath()` does not recognize it.

Comment: Path is on the server or the client?

Comment: @Jackson Pope, at Server

Comment: @down voter, care to answer or at least give the reason.

Comment: Is the path relative to a page?

Answer (score 2):

If the path is relative to the current page, you can use `Page.MapPath()`

http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.web.ui.page.mappath.aspx

Answer (score 1):

You want:

```
using System.IO;

Path.GetFullPath("../../../../Items/Image/rise.png");
```

Comment: Sorry, that does not work, it results in C:\Program Files\Items\Image\rise.png

Comment: @41K: It works based on the current directory (as do the `..`s). Where is the application you're coding running from?

Comment: +1 for your attempt, but still I am not getting result as expected. Actually I am debugging, When I set Environment.CurrentDirectory=HttpContext.Server.MapPath("~") and called your method, the result is changed but it is still not expected, I am getting "C:\Users\dev\Items\Image\rise.png"